# How to work with global query params

Tags: ember.js

I have some query params which I don't want to loose when I switch from one route to another. From the docs, the solution seems to be the use of global query params, set up on `ApplicationController`.

Let's say my setup is :

- A page with a list of objects displayed and some criterias on the left to filter this list. We may call the related controller `ListController`. All the criterias have to be query params.
- When an object from the first page is clicked, the whole page is replaced by a detailed view of that object. From this page I need to be able to go back to my previously filtered list and consequently keep my query params.

I need to access to `ApplicationController`'s global query params from `ListController` for some manipulations. It's easy :

```
App.ListController = App.ArrayController.extend({
   needs: "application",
   qp: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application"),
   ....
```

When a criteria changes, the filtering operation is done server side, so I need to refresh `ListRoute` when a query params changes.

How to do this from `ApplicationRoute` ?

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
      queryParamsDidChange: function () {
         var listRoute = ??????;
         listRoute.refresh();
      }
   }
}
```

What do you think of the whole setup ? Am I on a good path ? I'm not sure...

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

The queryParams are defined in a route. This will be the "parent", with implications for its children.

```
queryParams:
  fooParam: 
    refreshModel: true
```

Setting refreshModel: true will trigger the `beforeModel:`, `model:`, and `afterModel:` hooks for the route as well as all descendant routes. Currently, there is no way to individually turn on or off this behavior for descendants.

And its controller

```
queryParams: ['fooParam']
fooParam: null
```

queryParams hook in the controller does not override the queryParams hook in the route, but rather, is necessary and complementary for the entire functionality to work. You should not put any of these belonging in the controller in the route, or what belongs in the route in the controller.

all query parameter keys need to be defined in the controller as well. The value of this hook is just the default value. It will still change according to the query parameter.

Then, any descendant route,

```
model: ->
  this.modelFor('parent').filterBy('childAttribute', this.paramsFor('parent').fooParam)
```

or if you want one (the first by default) record:

```
model: ->
  this.modelFor('parent').findBy('childAttribute', this.paramsFor('parent').fooParam)
```